# ANDENGINE Old [Splash Screen Error]

Tags: android, andengine, splash-screen, 2d-games

I'm a beginner with Andengine, so I take GLSE1 to practise my first game code. I tried to display a splash screen, but it always show errors in "Texture"(cannot instantiate the type texture), "createFromAsset".

My complete code for the splash screen below:

```
package com.example.first.aq2;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

public class AQ2 extends BaseGameActivity {

    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================
    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 480;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 320;
    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Texture mTexture;
    private TextureRegion mSplashTextureRegion;
    // ===========================================================
    // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
    // ===========================================================
    @Override
    public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH,  CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera));
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadResources() {
    this.mTexture = new Texture(512, 512,TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    this.mSplashTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture,this, "gfx/Splashscreen.png", 0, 0);
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);
    }
    @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    final Scene scene = new Scene(1);
    /* Center the splash on the camera. */
    final int centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mSplashTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
    final int centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mSplashTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
    /* Create the sprite and add it to the scene. */
    final Sprite splash = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mSplashTextureRegion);
    scene.getLastChild().attachChild(splash);
    return scene;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete() {
    }
    }
    enter code here
```

help me to do the first step

Comment: WHAT ERROR ARE YOU TALKING ABOUT?

Comment: In "Texture"(cannot instantiate the type texture), line: this.mTexture = new Texture(512, 512,TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are using the image with the size greater than the width and height mentioned in the texture. Check the width and height of the image and Try increasing the width and height of the texture and check if it works
OR 
Try change your texture to **BitmapTextureAtlas** and try this

private BitmapTextureAtlas mtexture;
    private TextureRegion mregion;

```
mtexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);     
mregion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mtexture, getApplicationContext(), "Splashscreen.png",0,0);
getEngine().getTextureManager().loadTexture(mtexture);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change to GLES2 - Anchor Center if you are still at the beginning.

Then:

```
mTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
mSplashTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(yourTexture, this, "gfx/Splashscreen.png"", 0, 0);
mTexture.load();
```

then:

final Sprite splash = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mSplashTextureRegion, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    scene.getLastChild().attachChild(splash);

- why do you attach it to last child entity?